# NodeJS Deployment Capacity Planning for AWS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I'm researching for the NodeJS deployment options and I'm thinking about using AWS but I don't seem to grasp the pricing as well how to go about deployment. My current solution consists of Express, along with several separate node modules, RabbitMQ and MySQL DB. For the time being I'm not expecting much load on the application just typical of your Enterprise Web Application. If say I were to estimate its requirements I would say I will need 4-8 CPU Cores and 8-16GB for application server and the same for MySQL server with 16-24 GB RAM with around 2 TB of total storage.

Can someone tell me what instance types would be better for my requirements and will I require separate instances for App Server, DB Server etc or I can setup it on the same instance? Secondly how easy will it to scale the requirements if future needs arise, can I switch the instance type and increase memory, CPU, storage etc easily?

Another thing how pricing works, will it calculate after the request comes to the cloud and how much resources did it consume or will I still gets charged even if no requests are coming in?

Bear in mind I have no experience with AWS and I'm simply looking to use it as a hosting site currently. What are your recommendations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions, many of them are unanswerable from us because *we don't know what your application resource demands are*.

> Can someone tell me what instance types would be better for my requirements

Not really. If you know which of your services require more CPU vs more RAM, you can look at the [instance descriptions](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) to see which type is best suited for your (some are optimized for CPU, some for disk, some for RAM, etc). Ultimately though, this is something only you can decide on (unless you have load-testing metrics that you can share with us).

> will I require separate instances for App Server, DB Server etc or I can setup it on the same instance?

You can do whatever you normally would with a desktop - it's a full-blown OS, the only difference is you have to explicitly configure the networking around it (who can access your host, on what ports, etc.). While it's advisable to have multiple hosts, if you're just testing at first, there's nothing wrong with launching everything on a single host for now while you get your feet wet.

> how easy will it to scale the requirements if future needs arise, can I switch the instance type and increase memory, CPU, storage etc easily?

Easy is relative. You can definitely spin up more instances, but how those instances scale *with your application* is something entirely different. How easy is it for your application to migrate to new hardware? Can you throw a load balancer in front of multiple boxes? These are questions you need to consider.

It's worth noting explicitly though that you can't upgrade existing machines with additional resources (except for storage). If you need more CPU, more memory, more bandwidth, it's a new instance type.

> how pricing works, will it calculate after the request comes to the cloud and how much resources did it consume or will I still gets charged even if no requests are coming in?

Amazon has [a pretty robust pricing description](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) that you should go over.

For base instances:

*Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour or per-second depending on which Amazon EC2 instances you run.*

But you also have to consider data rates (on the same page), as well as storage costs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. So, I can't scale the same instance with additional resources, that's a bummer. Anyway, I know you don't know the load metrics but just to give me an estimate for the hardware I listed above or any strategy to go about it. Right now I don't even have the complete app running just some guestimates but I was asked by my boss for hosting comparisons. Another thing will I have to pay separately for storage and what if I want VPN connections etc with different OnPrem solutions? Will I need to pay separately for that?

Comment: Everything you've asked is already clearly laid out on their pricing documentation -- you've specified the amount of RAM and number of CPUs you think you'll need; just look at the instance types that best align with that setup, and the price that goes with them. If you're looking for a way to play with costs, use https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was helpful. I just can't understand one thing, would I need to pay separately for establishing VPN connectivity with multiple OnPrem services. My solution will have many connections with multiple OnPrem solutions that will have different IP etc. Secondly I will also require a public IP for my website. All of that will be charged separately and in case yes, what are the treminology on AWS I'm looking for? Like I said I'm new to cloud/AWS and I don't understand the terms Elastic IP, public Elastic IP and VPC etc.